# Linux and Crunch password generator

Tags: linux, passwords

I have a program which requires one variable -e, ./program  -e

I know how to use crunch in linux using pipe ./program | crunch etc

but I do not know how to add the first variable -e

is there a way I can just run crunch in the middle of a command?

*** btw a user of mine has lost the password to an important zip file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as that:

```
./program -e | crunch etc
```

Considering your comment below you might give this a try:

```
./program `crunch etc` -e
```

Comment: the -e need to come after the crunch command. otherwise the output would be ./program -e AAAAAAA, I need ./program AAAAAAA -e. Will that work?

Comment: Oh, that is something _completely different. So you need to _feedd the output of a command into another command_?

Comment: arkascha, yeah basically.

Comment: I added an approach for that to the question. Does that one help? If not, then I suggest you make a short bash script instead where you can save the output of one command to a variable and reuse it inside another call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, looks like I will have to try and make a script.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer is rather:
crunch | xargs -I{} ./program -e {}

see man xargs for more explanations (-I simply gives a reuseable name to what is read on the input stream...)

Comment: Could you please add more details about your solution?